# Package causing blank page for NO reason

Tags: formatting, packages, blank-page, texpad

After simply adding `\usepackage{blochsphere}`, an unwanted extra blank page at the beginning of the document is added - what is going on here?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blochsphere}

\title{error}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
    bla
\end{document}
```

logfile:

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode (preloaded format=latex 2017.10.25)  10 AUG 2018 19:20
**&latex
(blocherr.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.12> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (blochsphere.sty
Package: blochsphere 2015/09/15 v1.1 blochsphere drawing package
Package: blochsphere 2015/08/17
(tikz.sty (pgf.sty (pgfrcs.sty (pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104
(pgfutil-common-lists.tex)) (pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
)) (pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(pgfcore.sty (graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
) (graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2015/04/1 Graphics configuration of vvtex
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: vvtex.def on input line 99.
(vvtex.def
File: vvtex.def 2017/10/21 v2.0
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
) (pgfsys.sty (pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17
(pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count87
\c@pgf@countb=\count88
\c@pgf@countc=\count89
\c@pgf@countd=\count90
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21
(pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-vvtex.def
(pgfsys-vvtex.def)) (pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count91
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count92
) (pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(color.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2015/09/1 Colour configuration of vvtex
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: vvtex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(pgfmath.code.tex (pgfmathcalc.code.tex (pgfmathutil.code.tex) (pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count93
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
) (pgfmathfunctions.code.tex (pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex))) (pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count94
)) (pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
) (pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
) (pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
) (pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count95
) (pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
) (pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
) (pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
) (pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
) (pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
) (pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count96
) (pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)
(pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
)) (pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
) (pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
) (pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
) (pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
) (pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
) (pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (pgffor.sty (pgfkeys.sty (pgfkeys.code.tex)) (pgfmath.sty (pgfmath.code.tex)) (pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
)) (tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
(pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count97
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count98
\tikznumberofchildren=\count99
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count100
\tikz@fig@count=\count101
(pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count102
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count103
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count104
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count105
(tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count106
) (environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
(trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)
\@envbody=\toks27
) (ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
(infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
) (etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
(ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)) (kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
(ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)) (tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex (tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex (pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen151
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen152
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen153
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen154
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen155
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count107
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen156
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen157
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box37
) (pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex)) (tikzlibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex (pgflibrarydecorations.markings.code.tex)) (tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2013/07/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex 2009/11/15 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
(pgflibraryfadings.code.tex
File: pgflibraryfadings.code.tex 2008/02/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.3)
))) (blocherr.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Overfull \vbox (260.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

[1

]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 5.

LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

[2] (blocherr.aux) )
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no blank page. Can you show the log file from running that example code?

Comment: I tried with the version from the log (apparently `2015/09/15` _and_ `2015/08/17` at the same time :P) and I get one page only. And according to CTAN there was one update only, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with the package...

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the issue is with TeXpad.

Comment: in my case, an extra blank page appears only after I include the package. without it, everything is fine - very strange

Comment: You are using a quite unusual pdf driver: pgfsys-vvtex.def and similar for graphics. This looks as if you are using modified files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The driver should be the one TeXpad uses by default. I did not install any other driver - nor would I know how to

Comment: sure but it means that we can't reproduce the problem as we don't have the drivers. Ask the texpad support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the support of texpad should be asked ...